# NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData crashing for NSDictionary of objects

Tags: swift3

In converting an app from Objective C to Swift 3, many of the data structures are no longer classes, but structs. In a particular function, I need to use the NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: function to encapsulate these structs before sending them over a network connection, so I've converted them to good old Objective-C objects. But the code below still crashes when I attempt to encode them.

```
enum CustomDataType:Int
{
    case CustomDataType0 = 0
    case CustomDataType1 = 1
    case CustomDataType2 = 2
    case CustomDataType3 = 3
    case CustomDataType4 = 4
}

func send(dataType:CustomDataType, dictionary: Dictionary<String, Any>)
{
   // convert everything into objects
    let dataTypeObject:NSNumber = NSNumber(integerLiteral: dataType.rawValue)
    let dataValueObject:NSDictionary = dictionary as NSDictionary
    let dataTypeObjectKey:NSString = "regis-type"
    let dataValueObjectKey:NSString = "regis-value"

    let transmissionData:NSDictionary = [dataTypeObjectKey : dataTypeObject, dataValueObjectKey :dataValueObject]

    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: transmissionData)
```

The last line produces a crash, and I'm baffled. Any thoughts?

Crash log:

[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170448df0
2017-02-22 17:10:10.338319 cd Swift[441:56841] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170448df0'

Comment: The result depends on what you are passing to your `dictionary` of `send(dataType:dictionary:)`. Very likely it contains something which cannot be archived, some sort of Swift enums possibly.

Comment: Confirmed. I wrote a converter routine yesterday and the bug was quashed.